# Read binary file line by line into textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file, binary

I have a binary file "blahblah.dat" that consists of data stored in a 16byte structure.
Each line in my file is 16 bytes long.

I want to read this file line by line, converting the binary data into decimal and then displaying it in a textbox.

I've had a search and can't seem to find anything suitable.

---

Using this code:

```
Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.dat", FileMode.Open))
        ' Loop through length of file.
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        Dim length As Integer = reader.BaseStream.Length
        While pos < 1024
            ' Read the integer.
            For i = 0 To 15
                Dim value As Decimal = reader.ReadByte
                ' Write to screen.
                Console.WriteLine(value)
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & value & ","
                pos += 1
            Next
            ' Add length of decimal in bytes to position.
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
        End While
    End Using
```

I got these results(which are what I think to be correct - I will confirm later on):

```
0,0,128,32,0,0,0,0,2,162,36,18,7,8,3,11,
0,3,128,32,0,0,0,0,1,138,37,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,128,40,0,0,0,0,0,113,38,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,128,40,0,0,0,0,3,66,38,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,128,40,0,0,0,0,2,42,39,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,18,40,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,226,40,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,202,41,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,178,42,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,154,43,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,106,43,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,82,44,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,58,45,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,34,46,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,242,46,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,218,47,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,195,48,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,146,48,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,122,49,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,98,50,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,74,51,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,26,51,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,3,52,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,234,53,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,187,53,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,163,54,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,139,55,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,115,56,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,67,56,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,43,57,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,19,58,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,227,58,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,203,59,18,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,1,179,0,19,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,0,156,1,19,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,3,108,1,19,7,8,3,11,
0,51,130,40,0,0,0,0,2,84,2,19,7,8,3,11,
0,0,128,32,0,0,0,0,3,172,9,19,7,8,3,11,
15,0,128,32,0,0,0,0,1,238,10,19,7,8,3,11,
15,0,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,44,11,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,80,11,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,0,151,12,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,197,12,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,1,10,13,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,3,57,13,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,1,140,14,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,3,192,14,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,13,15,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,0,95,16,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,145,16,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,0,225,17,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,3,26,17,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,1,104,18,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,3,152,18,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,1,229,19,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,0,44,20,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,88,20,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,0,159,21,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,213,21,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,1,30,22,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,3,75,22,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,1,145,23,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,3,193,23,19,7,8,3,11,
15,51,128,8,0,0,0,0,2,12,24,19,7,8,3,11,
```

Would that be the best way to get the data or is there any way to tidy up the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    ' Create the reader in a Using statement.
    ' ... Use File.Open to open the existing binary file.
    Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open("blahblah.dat", FileMode.Open))
        ' Loop through length of file.
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        Dim length As Integer = reader.BaseStream.Length
        While pos < length
        ' Read the integer.
        Dim value As Decimal = reader.ReadDecimal()
        ' Write to screen.
        Console.WriteLine(value)
        ' Add length of decimal in bytes to position.
        pos += 16
        End While
    End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I'm creating this in a windows form so I would like to have the event happen when I press a button. Also is there any way to read it line by line rather than all in one go as the file is approx. 3.5mb

Comment: so call this method from inside an event

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't get the output that I expected though. Is there a way to read the raw data from the file? It read the full line as decimal (which is what I asked for) but I need to read it as a string if possible as I need to split the data up.

Comment: try reader.ReadString();, infact of you need to convert entire binary file to string you can directly pass array of bytes from fileload to System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes), which will give you a long string

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the code I've used to get my data and it is how it should be. - I now have a problem with the 9th and 10th figure, these are the lsb and msb respectively for time data (milliseconds) how would I go about using/combining these two figures to create one figure that is time in milliseconds?

Comment: Sorted it now. Thanks very much for your help. I really appreciate it.